# How to calculate: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-m} \frac{1}{n-k} {n-m \choose k}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

How to calculate:
$$\sum _{k=0}^{n-m} \frac{1}{n-k} {n-m \choose k}.$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{1}{n-k} = \int_0^1 x^{n-k-1} dx$. Hence,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-m} \frac{1}{n-k}\binom{n-m}k = \int_0^1 dx \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} x^{n-k-1}\binom{n-m}k = \int_0^1 x^{m-1}(1+x)^{n-m}dx = (-1)^m B_{-1}(m,n-m+1),$$
where $B_{\cdot}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

Comment: Wow, this is a very beautiful solution, thank you! @Max

Answer (score 4):

Just to demonstrate  abilities of CASes. Mathematica produces

```
Sum[1/(n - k)*Binomial[n - m, k], {k, 0, n - m}] // FullSimplify
```

> $(-1)^{n+1} B_{-1}(-n,-m+n+1) $

Maple says

```
simplify(sum(binomial(n-m, k)/(n-k), k = 0 .. n-m))
```

> $$-{\frac {{\it JacobiP} \left( n-m,-n,-n+m-1,3 \right)  \left( -n-1
>  \right) !\, \left( n-m \right) !}{ \left( -m \right) !}}
>  $$

Comment: Those factorials of negative integers in the Maple answer are a problem.  Doing it slightly differently gives $(-1)^{n+m} \operatorname{JacobiP}(n-m,-n,-n+m-1,3)(n-m)!\,(m-1)!/n!$.

Comment: @Brendan McKay: Thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you like, there is a 2nd-order recurrence for it.

Let $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac1{n-k}\binom{n-m}k$. Then,
$$(n+2)a_{n+2}+(m-3n-4)a_{n+1}+2(n+1-m)a_n=0.$$